# Include via wildcard in unbound.conf

Tags: configuration, debian-wheezy, wildcard

According to its [man page](https://www.unbound.net/documentation/unbound.conf.html) (Section **FORMAT**) unbound's configuration directive `include:` *"[...] can  be  used  to  include  multiple files, see glob(7)."*

Now, regardless of whether the directive is

```
include: /etc/unbound/zones/*.conf
```

or a general, all including

```
include: /etc/unbound/zones/*
```

The message I receive upon service start is:

```
Restarting recursive DNS server: unbound/etc/unbound/unbound.conf:17: error: 
     cannot open include file '/etc/unbound/zone/*': No such file or directory
read /etc/unbound/unbound.conf failed: 1 errors in configuration file
[1420997682] unbound[17125:0] fatal error: Could not read config file: 
     /etc/unbound/unbound.conf
```

Only fully qualified file names work.

How do I have to interpret what the man page states? Am I interpreting it wrong? `glob` is supposed to allow wildcards, right?

---

System info: Debian Wheezy on RasPi, Unbound 1.4.17-3+deb7u2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the 1.4.17-3+deb7u2 version of the `unbound.conf(5)` man page says about `include`:

> ```
>   Files  can be included using the include: directive. It can appear any‐
>   where, and takes a single filename as an argument.  Processing  contin‐
>   ues  as  if  the text from the included file was copied into the config
>   file at that point.  If also using chroot, using full  path  names  for
>   the  included  files  works,  relative pathnames for the included names
>   work  if  the  directory  where  the  daemon  is  started  equals   its
>   chroot/working directory.
> ```

As you can see, the sentence in this section that references wildcards and `glob` in the man page on the unbound web site (man page from the current version, at this time 1.5.1) does not exist in the man page for 1.4.17-3+deb7u2.

I imagine that using `glob` for the `include` statement is simply a feature that was introduced in a later version.

Comment: Why didn't I check that out first... Thanks for the obvious, though. I shall now use this version of unbound to resolve the address `unbound.net` and download a more recent version of it. Thanks again.